# App Localizations section in itunes for localization of meta data of an app already in appstore

Tags: ios, localization, app-store-connect

Can I add additional localization to meta data of an app already in appstore (status - ready for sale) from the App Localizations section in itunes connect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately Apple requires that your app be in an *Editable* state. From the iTunes Connect guide, Apple explains that you can make only these changes to your app once it is Ready for Sale:

> **Editing app-level information, such as rights and pricing, Game Center and iAd Network settings, and in-app purchases**
>
> **Editing version-level information, such as app metadata and ratings**

That means you can edit EXISTING metadata only. If you've already added a German localization, for example, you can update those keywords or app description. However, you cannot add a NEW language. To do so you must create a new version of your app and submit the update.

See this step-by-step tutorial for [Adding a New Localization of your App Description](http://www.ibabbleon.com/add-localized-app-store-description-tutorial.html)